# Returning value from Start-Process argument

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell function (Add-EventLogSource) that checks if an event log source exists. If it does not exist and the shell is not elevated, I start a new, elevated shell and call the function again.

I can't seem to get the return values correct. If the event log source does not exist, and I call Add-EventLogSource, I am not getting the return value all the way back to instance that originally called Add-EventLogSource. Can anyone see the problem? The code looks like this:

```
Function Add-EventLogSource {
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    $EventLogSource
)

    # Check if $EventLogSource exists as a source. If the shell is not elevated and the check fails to access the Security log, assume the source does not exist.
    Try {
        $sourceExists = [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists("$EventLogSource")
    }
    Catch {
        $sourceExists = $False
    }

    If ((([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator”)) -AND ($sourceExists -eq $False)) { # Shell is elevated...
        Try {
            New-EventLog –LogName Application –Source $EventLogSource -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Catch {
            Return "Error"
        }

        Return "Created"
    }
    ElseIf ($sourceExists -eq $False) {
        $return = Start-Process PowerShell –Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "Add-EventLogSource -EventLogSource $EventLogSource; start-sleep 5" -Wait

        Return $return
    }
    Else {
        Return "Exists"
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The usual technique is to check for elevation and tell the user to elevate to do whatever requires elevation rather than trying to elevate automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I've done it that way before too. In this case, it isn't the elevation that's the problem. When I elevate, the function works, but I'm not getting the return value "Created" back from the elevated shell.

Comment: I wouldn't expect what you are trying to do to work.